# Javascript disabled for local network, but not internet

Tags: javascript, local-network

I have run into a bizarre situation on a single computer in my office.  All other computers work as they should.

What happens is web pages hosted on the internal server (local network: 192.168.1.6) will not execute any of the javascript functionality on the internal web application.  Meaning the buttons, jquery and ajax functionality do nothing.

All 3 browsers on this single computer do not have any javascript functionality: not IE, not Firefox, not Chrome.  They just do nothing when you click things.

I have tried uninstalling Firefox and reinstalling ... no change.

Web pages on the internet (such as Gmail or google) work just fine.

We have also tried turning off the virus protection (EmsiSoft) but to no avail.

Does anybody have any ideas short of wiping the machine?  Is this a virus? Is it a "feature" of EmsiSoft?

Comment: Are you sure JS files are downloadable for this computer?

Comment: What does your web console print?

Comment: Yes, check the dev tools console and network activity panels.

Comment: Open up IE/Chrome and look at what the settings for the intranet setting are in the internet options. http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/images/tech/750-intranet-browsing-ie10-epm2.png

Comment: Do you see the file referenced in the network panel of chrom debugger? If so what happens when you click it?

Comment: What exactly am I trying to view/verify with the dev tools?  I can see the .js files in Firebug.  Its just none of the browsers actually run the javascript.

Comment: In Chrome dev tools, I can make an alert(); box pop-up ... but it still isn't running my javascript.  Some of the javascript is actually in-line on the web page.  Could this be a virus or "feature" of EmsiSoft?

Comment: This may be an issue with EmsiSoft ... I turned off the "Surf Protection" and immediately the javascript began working.